# Google Fitness API HistoryAPI.deleteData() not working

Tags: java, android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm building a step counter app with the Google Fitness API.

I can get the daily steps with HistoyAPI.readDailyTotal()

```
private void getTodaySteps() {
    PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
    if (result != null) {
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
            final long total = totalSet.isEmpty()
                    ? 0
                    : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Steps today: " + total);
                    tv_StepsToday.setText("" + total);
                    if (total >= (stepsToday + stepsNow)) {
                        stepsNow = 0;
                        stepsToday = total;
                        publishTodaysStepData();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // handle failure
            Log.e(TAG, "Não foi possível obter o histórico de passos");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "result nulo!");
    }
}
```

I'm also using the SensorAPI to get the delta steps from the last read, then I just add the two and get a nice responsive step counter.

```
private void subscribeSteps() {
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        if (status.getStatusCode()
                                == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void unsubscribeStepsAndDeleteData() {
    Fitness.RecordingApi.unsubscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully unsubscribed for data type: step count delta");
                        deleteData();
                    } else {
                        // Subscription not removed
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to unsubscribe for data type: step count delta");
                    }
                }
            });
}
private void getLiveSteps() {
    if (!listenerRegistered) {
        Log.v(TAG, "mandando requisição do sensor...");
        SensorRequest req = new SensorRequest.Builder()
                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();


        OnDataPointListener listener = new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(final DataPoint dataPoint) {
                Log.v(TAG, "new datapoint: " + dataPoint.toString());
                for (final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (dataPoint.getTimestampNanos() != oldTimeStampNanos) {
                                oldTimeStampNanos = dataPoint.getTimestampNanos();
                                long result = (long) dataPoint.getValue(field).asInt();
                                Log.i(TAG, "steps now: " + result);
                                stepsNow += result;
                                publishTodaysStepData();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mClient, req, listener).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                    listenerRegistered = true;
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However I can't clear the daily steps. I'm trying to use the code on the [API exemples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistoryApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistoryapi/MainActivity.java):

```
private void deleteData() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Deleting today's step count data");

    // [START delete_dataset]
    // Set a start and end time for our data, using a start time of 1 day before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    //  Create a delete request object, providing a data type and a time interval
    DataDeleteRequest request = new DataDeleteRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .build();

    // Invoke the History API with the Google API client object and delete request, and then
    // specify a callback that will check the result.
    Fitness.HistoryApi.deleteData(mClient, request)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully deleted today's step count data");
                    } else {
                        // The deletion will fail if the requesting app tries to delete data
                        // that it did not insert.
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to delete today's step count data");
                    }
                }
    });
    // [END delete_dataset]
}
```

Is it a bug, or I'm just doing something wrong?

**--Edit:**
my GoogleApiClient Builder

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                            // Put application specific code here.subscribeSteps();
                            refreashAll();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                // Show the localized error dialog
                                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                        LoginActivity.this, 0).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
                            // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
                            // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
                            if (!authInProgress) {
                                try {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                    authInProgress = true;
                                    result.startResolutionForResult(LoginActivity.this,
                                            REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,
                                            "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build();

}
```

and my log:

`07-20 09:03:53.161  10647-10647/br.com.penseavanti.gump I/LoginActivity﹕ Successfully unsubscribed for data type: step count delta
07-20 09:03:53.161  10647-10647/br.com.penseavanti.gump I/LoginActivity﹕ Deleting today's step count data
07-20 09:03:53.209  10647-10647/br.com.penseavanti.gump I/LoginActivity﹕ Successfully deleted today's step count data
07-20 09:03:53.388  10647-10647/br.com.penseavanti.gump I/LoginActivity﹕ Steps today: 509
07-20 09:03:53.434  10647-10647/br.com.penseavanti.gump I/LoginActivity﹕ Successfully subscribed!`

Comment: My understanding is that you can only delete data that was added by your app. You can't delete data added by other apps, only read it. Are you trying to delete data that your app added? Or are you trying to delete data that was added by the Google Fit app?

Comment: I'm trying to delete data that my app recorded, I don't even have the Google Fit app installed

Comment: Can you post the code for your GoogleApiClient builder? Are you adding the HISTORY_API to your builder? You could also try calling deleteAllData and deleteAllSessions on your delete request. Depending on how you're adding the data to the Fit API, it could be attached to a session or activity that is preventing it from deleting properly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm adding HISTORY_API, SENSORS_API and RECORDING_API. I've tried deleting all data and all session, but the result was the same.

Comment: What I don't get is that status.isSuccess() is true. Even so, my steps are still there. I've edited my question with the log.

Comment: I can remove data that was added using the SessionsApi and HistoryApi but when using the RecordingApi I'm not able to remove the data. Your delete code looks good, this is either a feature or a bug specific to the RecordingApi.